# mysql query takes too long because of wrong indexes usage

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have the following query in mysql,

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(COALESCE(amount, 0)), 0) as sum_amount,
       COALESCE(sum(COALESCE(fees_amount, 0)), 0) as sum_fees_amount
FROM incoming_operation
WHERE status = 'CLEARED' 
  and merchant_id = ? 
  and shop_id IN (?) 
  and currency = ? 
  and cycle_id is null
FOR UPDATE
```

where `shop_id,currency,status` and  `cycle_id` are indexed

`CREATE INDEX payout_operation_update ON incoming_operation(shop_id,currency,status);`

`CREATE INDEX cycle_id_index ON incoming_operation (cycle_id);`

the value of cycle_id is mostly NULL in the DB.
the values of `shop_id,currency,status` are unique in the DB

when running the above query, the query ran for a very long time (2 hours) and I got a lock where other operations couldnt update any row in the DB.

from running the query with explain ive seen that it used both indexes: `shop_id,currency,status` and  `cycle_id`.

can i assume that using `payout_operation_update(shop_id,currency,status)` index only will make the query quicker?

my assumption is that because of using `cycle_id_index`, all other rows (whos cycle_id is null) were also locked, and using only `payout_operation_update(shop_id,currency,status)` index will lock only the relevant rows (those that apply to filter of `shop_id,currency,status`)

that's the values i got from EXPLAIN:

```
SIMPLE
1   
incoming_operation
index_merge 
payout_operation_update,status_expected_clear_datetime,merchant_status_expected_clear_datetime,cycle_id_index   
payout_operation_update,cycle_id_index  
361,9       
922125  
10.00
Using intersect(payout_operation_update,cycle_id_index); 
Using where
```

is that assumption valid?

Comment: a) Please provide the actual explain output. You might not have read it correctly. b) If "shop_id,currency,status" is unique, and given that currency and status are constants in your query, your query will apply to at most n rows, where n is the number of ids in `and shop_id IN (?)`. Unless n is in the billions, taking 2 hours for this indicates some underlying problem. As a guess: Most likely, the actual processing time for your query is some seconds, but it might waits 1 hour 59 minutes and 55 seconds for other locks because you use "for update" a lot in all your queries.